# Why won't this answer to project euler number 4 work properly?

Tags: python

```
numbers = []
palindromes = []
for i in range (100,999):
    for j in range(100,999):
        number = i * j
        test = str(number)
        if test == test[::-1]:
            palindromes.append(number)     

print(palindromes[-1])
```

This code gives back palindromes. However it gives back 580085, which is far from 906609 which is correct. Is there something in the code that makes it quit early?

Comment: Are you printing debugging info as this runs?

Comment: `sorted(palindromes)[-1]`

Answer (score 3):

Your list does contain all the palindromes in that range, but not necessarily in a sorted order; the biggest one is somewhere in the middle. Use `max` to retrieve it.

```
print(max(palindromes))
```